# Express JS redirect all paths to static maintenance page

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, redirect

I have an Angular Web App with a Express Node JS Backend and I would like to display a static Under construction page, so that web app cannot be used during a specific time period.
In my current setup I have a initStaticPages function (please see below), which inits all the routes. I also added a new Page which is served via /maintenance.

When writing a middleware which always redirects to /maintenance and adding this middleware to all routes, I get a too many redirects error and the web app is down. Adding middleware to all routes except index page "/" is working, but not the behaviour I wanted to achieve. Anybody knows how to solve this? Would appreciate any help. Thanks a lot

router.js

```
const initStaticPages = (router) => {
  router.use('/', checkMaintenanceMode, express.static('public'))
  router.use('/main', checkMaintenanceMode, requireAccess, express.static('public'))
  router.use('/login', checkMaintenanceMode, express.static('public'))
  router.use('/logout', checkMaintenanceMode, express.static('public'))
  router.use('/logout?reason=timeout', checkMaintenanceMode, express.static('public'))
  router.use('/requestHistory', checkMaintenanceMode, requireAccess, express.static('public'))
  router.use('/recurringRequest', checkMaintenanceMode, requireAccess, express.static('public'))
  router.use('/maintenance', express.static('public'))
}

module.exports = () => {
  const router = express.Router()
  initStaticPages(router)
  return router
}
```

Simple Middleware would be like this: There will be also some conditions, but for simplicity I left it out.

```
const checkMaintenanceMode = (req, res, next) => {
    res.redirect('/maintenance/')
}
```

main.js

```
const app = require('express')()
const router = require('./router')()
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')
const compression = require('compression')

const port = process.env.PORT

app.use(compression())
app.use(cookieParser())
app.use(router)

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Running on port ${port}`))
```

Second Error after adjusting the ordering of routes:
Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.

In the following the content of public folder and maintenance container.
The index.html has some router-outlet included and serves the specific Container Component. In this case /maintenance.
Apparently when adding the middleware to / route, it's throwing the error from above and showing a blank page.

```js
/app/frontend/app/container/maintenance: 
   maintenance.component.css
   maintenance.component.html 
   maintenance.component.ts
   
/app/server/public: 
   assets 
   index.html
   vendor-es2015.3f2dce1d421f11b1eba1.js
   vendor-es2015.3f2dce1d421f11b1eba1.js.map
   vendor-es5.3f2dce1d421f11b1eba1.js
   vendor-es5.3f2dce1d421f11b1eba1.js.map
   polyfills-es5.34831379c55aac23d35e.js
   polyfills-es5.34831379c55aac23d35e.js.map
   main-es2015.730bc485b11bbd634316.js
   main-es2015.730bc485b11bbd634316.js.map
   polyfills-es2015.8c0828ece2f5d1fedbfb.js
   polyfills-es2015.8c0828ece2f5d1fedbfb.js.map
   main-es5.730bc485b11bbd634316.js main-es5.730bc485b11bbd634316.js.map
   runtime-es2015.dc25f63d6f9e75106165.js
   runtime-es2015.dc25f63d6f9e75106165.js.map
   runtime-es5.dc25f63d6f9e75106165.js
   runtime-es5.dc25f63d6f9e75106165.js.map 3rdpartylicenses.txt
   jsoneditor-icons.15f2789dd231f36d43a4.svg
   styles.9211410addacf27114df.css styles.9211410addacf27114df.css.map
```

Comment: In the scenario where you’re seeing a “too many redirects” error, are you also applying the `checkMaintenanceMode` middleware to the `/maintenance` route? Can you edit your code to be an [mre] of the actual issue you’re seeing?

Comment: @esqew edited the code snippet, middleware is not applied to maintenance route

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a case of specificity. Your routes should be defined from most specific to most general.

`/` is a route that will match literally anything including `/maintenance`. So you hit any route `/` is getting hit, then it redirects to `/maintenance` which obv matches with `/` and a cycle is created.

```
  router.use('/main', checkMaintenanceMode, requireAccess, express.static('public'))
  router.use('/login', checkMaintenanceMode, express.static('public'))
  router.use('/logout?reason=timeout', checkMaintenanceMode, express.static('public'))
  router.use('/logout', checkMaintenanceMode, express.static('public'))
  router.use('/requestHistory', checkMaintenanceMode, requireAccess, express.static('public'))
  router.use('/recurringRequest', checkMaintenanceMode, requireAccess, express.static('public'))
  router.use('/maintenance', express.static('public'))
  router.use('/', checkMaintenanceMode, express.static('public'))
```

Note: using similar logic I reordered your `/logout` routes. Not related to the question though.

Comment: Thanks for your response. This helped a lot. Only issue is now, that I get a blank page with the error: **bold(Failed to load module script, expected a java script module, but server responded with a MIME type of "text/html"). I have the suspicion, that it redirects to maintenance and expects styles etc there, but they are located in the root? Any idea about this?

Comment: That will depend on what you have inside your `public` folder. And what are you hitting as URL?

Comment: I'm hitting the / route. When I remove the middleware from there, it's working. I added the public folder content to the post above. Maintenance is a component which will be injected into index.html via route-outlet. But somehow the redirecting thinks, moving to a different folder?